# What is the fourier transform of $xe^{-x}$ for $x \in (-\infty, \infty)$?

Tags: fourier-transform

Calculating $\mathcal{F}[xe^{-x}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-x}e^{i \omega x} dx$ gives me an infinite value whereas i need it to converge! Is there another way to calculate this? I can't find it on tables!

Comment: You should find that the integral converges.  It's straightforward to find with integration by parts

Comment: @qbert Either is fine - the use of positive/negative is interchangable

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Are you sure? I've tried manually and on wolfram - https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+xe%5E(-x)e%5E(iwx)+dx++from+-infinity+to+infinity

Comment: $xe^{-x}$ has exponential growth at $-\infty$.  It doesn't make sense to take the fourier transform at all, even in a generalized sense.

Comment: It does not converge - the integrand blows up at $-\infty$.

Comment: Whoops, my mistake.  I was thinking of a one-sided transform